# React-Native get number of incoming call

Tags: react-native

I'm a newbie to react-native. I would like to check if there is any library to get phone number of incoming call?

I tried Googling but no satisfactory answer. I could find code for Android, but then in react-native i need to write custom code. Let me know if you know any such library

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: This is late reply and can help others - You must try https://github.com/wscodelabs/react-native-call-log using this you can then pull the recent call from json array and get the phone number

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-detection
Described there code from snippet not full, *new CallDetectorManager((event)=> {})* actually has one more argument, so you can use it like 
*new CallDetectorManager((event, **phonenumber**)=> {})*

Comment: Is there any video explaining how to use? I followed the tutorial, but it doesn't work.